# How do I make a loop that prompts the user to enter data every time they enter an invalid data type?

Tags: c#

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter value for Monday : ");
        milesMon = Console.ReadLine();



        try
        {
            dblMon = double.Parse(milesMon);



        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid number - a default of 0 has been set");
            dblMon = 0;

            while (true) break;

                Console.WriteLine("Enter value for Monday : ");
            milesMon = Console.ReadLine();
```

In it's current state the code only prompts the user after they enter incorrect data the first time they do it, I would like to know how to make it so it happens every time.

-Thanks

Comment: don't you need an exit condition also? If you add while you need some condition to break the loop too.else it will be infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a do or while loop to keep repeating the prompt until a valid double is entered.  You should also consider adding some form of exit keywords.  Like if they enter "exit, quit, q" etc.. Have it terminate the app instead of loop back around.  However being a console app, ctrl + c will close it regardless of what it's doing (it's the kill command) but not everyone knows that.

```
bool repeat = true;
var dblMilesMon = (double)0;
do 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter value for Monday : ");
    var strMilesMon = Console.ReadLine();
    if (!double.TryParse(strMilesMon, out dblMilesMon)) 
        Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid number - please enter a numeric value.")          
    else
        repeat = false; 
}while (repeat);

//do something with dblMilesMon
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TryParse()` to convert the input string to double, it will return false if the conversion failed; based on that input you can prompt the user that whether the input is valid or not. and this will loop until the user enter `Exit`

```
 string inputVal = "";
 double inputDoubleVal;
 while (inputVal == "Exit")
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Enter value for Monday : ");
      inputVal = Console.ReadLine();
      if (double.TryParse(inputVal, out  inputDoubleVal))
       {
          //Process with your double value
       }
      else
       {
         Console.WriteLine("You entered an invalid number - a default of 0 has been set");
       }
   }
```

Comment: Much better good sir. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to write a loop. While the input is invalid, prompt the user. So you should have a `bool` variable called `valid` to indicate whether the input is valid. And than a while loop like this:

```
while (!valid) {
    //...
}
```

In the while loop, prompt the user. So the code looks like this:

```
bool valid = false;
int input = 0;

while (!valid) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Prompt");
    try 
    {
        input = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());
        valid = true;
    } 
    catch {}
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` is same as `parse` it will throws exception is failed to convert

Comment: @un-lucky Yes, if an exception is thrown, the catch block will catch it. And the loop will start another iteration.

Comment: Using exceptions for program flow is a very bad idea. That's why the TryParse methods were added to the framework to avoid this

Comment: @un-lucky, agreed.  Try catches should be used for catching unexpected errors, like a divide by zero error if this were a calculator console input.  Flow problems should always be solved without try/catch where possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can use recursion to create your end-less loop without using a `for` or `while`. 
Also, instead of a try-catch statement, better use a `TryParse`
Doc ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384043.aspx

```
public int readInput(){
  int val = 0;
  Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid int");
  string enteredVal = Console.ReadLine();
  bool result = int.TryParse(enteredVal, out val);
  if(result)
    return val;
  Console.writeLine("Try again, only int values allowed");
  return readInput();
}


int val = readInput();
```